# Hide element in p5.js not working as expected

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm making this game where players have an option to choose their character.
The sketch.js file looks something like this:

```js
if (gameState === 1) { //player chooses his/her character
      for (var i = 0; i < mazeWalls.length; i++) {
        mazeWalls[i].visible = false;
      }
      /** Creating a character form.
       */
      charChosing = new CharacterForm();
    } else
      if (gameState === 2) { //player plays the game
        clear();
        charChosing.hide();
        playerObj.sprite.visible = true;
        form.hide();
        for (var i = 0; i < mazeWalls.length; i++) {
          mazeWalls[i].visible = true;
          //player.collide(mazeWalls[i]);
        }
```

Here, when gameState is 1, the player chooses a character by clicking on one of the buttons. On clicking the button, the gameState turns to 2 and the buttons are supposed to get hidden. The hide function is defined in the class definition.

The code for class CharacterForm is this:

```
class CharacterForm {
    constructor() {
        this.button1 = createButton("c1");
        this.button1.position(250, 300);
        this.button2 = createButton("c2");
        this.button2.position(300, 300);
        this.button3 = createButton("c3");
        this.button3.position(350, 300);
        this.button4 = createButton("c4");
        this.button4.position(400, 300);
        this.button1.mousePressed(() => {
            gameState = 2;
            playerObj.character = "ch1";
            this.button1.hide();
            this.button2.hide();
            this.button3.hide();
            this.button4.hide();
        });
        this.button2.mousePressed(() => {
            gameState = 2;
            playerObj.character = "ch2";

            this.button1.hide();
            this.button2.hide();
            this.button3.hide();
            this.button4.hide();
        });
        this.button3.mousePressed(() => {
            gameState = 2;
            playerObj.character = "ch3";

            this.button1.hide();
            this.button2.hide();
            this.button3.hide();
            this.button4.hide();
        });
        this.button4.mousePressed(() => {
            gameState = 2;
            playerObj.character = "ch4";

            this.button1.hide();
            this.button2.hide();
            this.button3.hide();
            this.button4.hide();
        });
    }
    hide() {
        this.button1.hide();
        this.button2.hide();
        this.button3.hide();
        this.button4.hide();
    }
}
```

The thing is, the buttons are still visible after calling hide function. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate if condition along with the code:

```js
if(gameState === "2") {
    playerObj.character = "ch3";

    this.button1.hide();
    this.button2.hide();
    this.button3.hide();
    this.button4.hide();
}
```